# How to declare an array containing generic type?

Tags: c#, generics

Say I have the following type:

```
public class Field<T>
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

How can I declare a variable that will contain an array of such Fields? I tried the following:

```
var customFields = new Field[]
{
    new Field<string> { Name = "nickname", Value = "Bob" },
    new Field<int> { Name = "age", Value = 42 },
    new Field<DateTime> { Name = "customer_since", Value = new DateTime(2000, 12, 1) }
};
```

but I get the following compile-time exception:

> Using the generic type 'Field' requires 1 type arguments

I also tried `var customFields = new Field<object>[]` but I get the following errors:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Field' to 'Field'
>
> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Field' to 'Field'
>
> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Field' to 'Field'

Comment: Each generic type, is a *different type*. Hence, you are trying to create an array of instances of different types. This is not possible. It's like trying to create an array that will store `string` and `int` values. However, you may take a look at [covariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As Matias said it can't be done that way because `Field<int>` and `Field<string>` are completely different types. What you can do is:

Create a base `Field` which is not generic:

```
public class Field
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Field<T> : Field
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

And then:

```
var customFields = new Field[]
{
    new Field<string> { Name = "nickname", Value = "Bob" },
    new Field<int> { Name = "age", Value = 42 },
    new Field<DateTime> { Name = "customer_since", Value = new DateTime(2000, 12, 1) }
};
```

As Matias commented a downcasting will be needed to get the `Value` of the different types. If for each different type of `Value` there is a specific logic to perform, a nice way to handle it will be to use the `Factory` design pattern. The factory will return for each `Field` a correct "`FieldHandler<T>`" that will downcast, do the operation and return what is needed.

Comment: FYI: You will have to downcast to generic type in order to get `Value` property of an element.

Comment: Very good idea! As Matias said, I'll have to cast in order to get the value, but in my specific case, not a big deal since I only support string, int and DateTime. By the way, anybody knows if I can restrict T to only these three types? Something along the lines of: `where T: string, int, DateTime`

Comment: For `int` and `DateTime` you can use the generic constraint of `struct` but for string...

Comment: @desautelsj I'm guessing the closest you can get is `T : IComparable`, but that will allow other types too. Basically, any type that can be compared to another.

Answer (score 2):

Another thing you can do is to simply use the common base class for all of those types - Object.

```
class Field
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Object Value { get; set; }
}
var customFields = new Field[]
{
    new Field { Name = "nickname ", Value = "Bob" },
    new Field { Name = "age", Value = 42 },
    new Field { Name = "customer_since", Value = new DateTime(2000, 12, 1) }
};
```

However, this would be offloading some type handling to the consumer of customFields, but should be fine if the Value types associated with a specific Field Name are known.

Comment: I agree with your first approach and that is why it got my upvote but the edition at the bottom - in that case.. why not to use generics?.. :)

Comment: You're right! I meant to add just for case of whitelisted types but even with Generics you can restrict with usage of `: Where T : [types allowed]`. Thanks for your upvote :)